# VBA equivalent to SQL 'in' function

Tags: vba

I'm writing a conditional statement in vba like

```
if(userID = 1 or userID = 2 or userID = 3 or userID = 4) then
...
```

I was wondering if there's a quicker, cleaner way to do this. Something like

```
if(userID in (1,2,3,4)) then
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Quicker in terms of less characters or efficiency of code?

Comment: @mehow Less characters.  My list will have less than 10 numbers to check, so performance differences between methods should be negligible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative would be:

```
select case userID
    case 1,2,3,4,5,6
       ' do something
end select
```

It conveys very good the meaning of the `if ... then ... else` construct.

Answer (score 5):

Another way

```
If UBound(Filter(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), UserID)) > -1 Then
```

Filter returns an array with the match. If there's no match, ubound = -1.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Application.Match` function on an array:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(userID, Split("1,2,3,4",","))) Then...
```

Comment: Doesn't `IsError` need `()` in this usage?

Comment: Yes, it does. Good catch. I have revised.

Answer (score 0):

**CW** because this matches the hypothetical example, but not likely a real use situation. However, `Like` is a good keyword to know.

```
If userID Like "[1-6]" Then
```

This is ok for single digit checks, but not real world multi-character user IDs.

i.e.

```
userID = 1
If userID Like "[1-6]" Then ' result is True
```

but

```
userID = 11
If userID Like "[1-6]" Then ' result is False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a basic function like this:

```
Function InArray(Match, SourceArray)
    InArray = False
    For i = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray)
        If SourceArray(i) = Match Then
            InArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Then you could say:

```
if InArray(userId, array(1,2,3,4)) then msgbox "Found it!"
```