# Can you list the possible values for a conditional statement in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new so sorry if this is a dumb question. I want to have an If statement stating if variable a is an element of a set of some integers then... Would it work if I write:

If a=1,6,12,19 Then

or would I have to write

If a=1 Or a=6 Or a=12 Or a=19 Then

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: You can use a case statement.  E.g. `Public Function test(a)
Select Case a
Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
'do something
End Select

End Function`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA equivalent to SQL 'in' function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553700/vba-equivalent-to-sql-in-function)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't write it as `if a=1,6,12,19 Then` but there are some alternatives that you can use and they are covered in the [answers to this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553700/vba-equivalent-to-sql-in-function). This is the one that I'd recommend in most cases.

```
select case userID
    case 1,2,3,4,5,6
       ' do something
end select
```

Comment: If there are ever anything more than 2 conditions, I always go with `select case`.  It's a beautiful thing!  Don't forget `case else`.  It's not required but it's a good habit to stick it in there before your `end select` so you don't forget the option is there :)

Answer (score 1):

The `InStr` function can handle it as a delimited substring within a string containing delimited options.

```
if cbool(instr(1, "x1x2x3x4x5x6x", format(a, "x0x"))) then
    'a is a number between 1 and 6
    debug.Print a & " is in 1,2,3,4,5,6"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Application.Match()` method

```
if Not IsError(Application.Match(a,array(1,6,12,19),0) Then
    your code
End If
```